# c++ object of one class wants to use method of object in another class

Tags: c++, class, object, instantiation

I'm converting my old c++ program into OOP and as things grow bigger I'm splitting it per class in .h and .cpp files. The first class compiled nicely into an object file. But my second class is dependant on that first class and now I run into problems. Here my very simplified "all in a single file" code that works:

```
class A {
public:
    void amethod(int) {
        ....code....
    }
};

A a_obj;   //object creation

class B {
public
    void bmethod(void) {
        a_obj.amethod(int);
    }
};

B b_obj;   //object creation

main() {
    b_obj.bmethod();
}
```

After deviding the code over different files my .h files look like:

```
//file A.h:
class A {
public:
    void amethod(int);
};

//file B.h
#include "A.h"
class B {
public
    void bmethod(void);
};
```

In the implementation of class B there is the call to a_obj.amethod() and even I understand that g++ has no way to know that a_obj is an object of class A as I did not even include the a_obj object creating anywhere in the code.

How to solve this ? Is it something simple that I need to put the object creation somewhere in my .h or .cpp file (note that lots of other classes are using the same amethod()). I can not make everything static as I also have classes with multiple objects (in fact the same way of working is all over the program). Or is this way of working completely wrong (which would explain why I can not find any solution for this).

Answer (score 1):

Is suggest you put more efforts in defining your interfaces.

If class `B` needs an instance of `A` to work, use parameters to pass an `A`:

```
class B {
public
    void bmethod(A & a_obj) {
        a_obj.amethod(int);
    }
};

main() {
    A a_obj;
    B b_obj;
    b_obj.bmethod(a_obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your original code uses global data (i.e. the declarations of `a_obj` and `b_obj` are global). Globals are generally a bad idea because they can cause several problems. The 'proper' OOP way to do it would be to instantiate those objects in `main()`, and pass them to whatever other objects need to access them. You could pass references, pointers, or copies, depending on your needs.

With that said, if you *really* want to continue doing it with global data, then you can use an `extern` declaration. In each *.cpp file where you access `a_obj`, include this:

```
extern A a_obj;
```

That basically tells the compiler that there is an object with that name, but it exists somewhere else. I really don't recommend this approach if you're serious about learning OOP though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are planning to use a_obj as global variable in other implementation file (.cpp). 
So in header file B.h type extern reference to this instance.

extern A a_obj;

This declaration should help compile your B.cpp file. And ask actual instance a_obj during linking.
I didnt try this code, but telling by my experience and my practice(way) of coding. Hope this solution helps, else am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to call A::amethod() class B needs the full definition of class A and its amethod(). So you need to #include A.h  before B.h in your .cpp files.

Next, if you address concrete a_obj object, you need to specify what that object is in order to link properly. In you first variant it was global object, so if it is what intended you can write: in A.cpp:

```
A a_obj;
```

in B.cpp:

```
extern a_obj;
// here you can call a_obj methods
```

But if these classes are so related that one calls methods of another, and also as I catched you need several objects of A and B, consider to connect these classes through inheritance:

```
class B : public A { 
public: 
    void bMethod(int n) {
       aMethod(n);  // base class method call
    }
// ...
```

or through delegation:

```
class B {
    A m_A;
public:
    void bMethod(int n) {
       m_A.aMethod(n);
    }
// ...
```

As mentioned earlier the way

```
void bMethod(A& a) {
    a.aMethod();
}
```

will work, but the language has built-in means to express classes relationships.

How to implement is more design question, you can read more about this in Stroustrup 3rd edition, '24.3.5 Use Relationships'.

In C++ you can also pass a pointer to a member function of one class into the member function of another class to call a method from completely unrelated class (say, some callback), you can use [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#idp98396200) and [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/bind/bind.html) for this. But it is advanced technique.

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed answers...I got it. I reviewed the code and decided to go for the "right way" instead of the "quick fix", Some classes that do not realy have a need for objects I will change into namespaces. For 2 others I can use delegation and for the last two I was already referencing the objects via vectors. I haven't changed everything yet, but I expect I'm on the right track now.